# How to find emoji from strings by golang?

Tags: go

I want to find if emoji is exists and replace to string(HTML unicode). (rune to string)

for example, this is the sentence

"i like you hahahah  hello."

to this is result.

"i like you hahahah &#128512 hello."

the emoji and the emoji position are randomly.

---

I will use upper code in below code.

```
    import "golang.org/x/text/encoding/korean"

    strings_with_emoji = "i like you hahahah  hello."
    var euckrEnc = korean.EUCKR.NewEncoder()
    euckrSubject, err := euckrEnc.String(strings_with_emoji)
```

there are no value of emoji.
https://uic.io/ko/charset/show/euc-kr/

so I got the error is ERRO[0002] encoding: rune not supported by encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can convert string to `[]rune` and every rune convert to ASCII or HTML entity

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    inp := "i like you hahahah  hello."

    res := ""
    runes := []rune(inp)
    
    for i := 0; i < len(runes); i++ {
        r := runes[i]
        if r < 128 {
            res += string(r)
        } else {
            res += "&#" + strconv.FormatInt(int64(r), 10) + ";"
        }
    }

    log.Printf("result html string: %v", res)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39577651/885098) provides a regular expression that can be used to match all emoji characters. You can combine that with `regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc` and `utf8.DecodeRuneInString` to replace all emojis with their corresponding HTML entity code like so:

```golang
import (
  "regexp"
  "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
  str := "i like you hahahah  hello."

  // full regular expression is provided below
  re := regexp.MustCompile(`[#*0-9]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|©\x{FE0F}?|...`)
  replaced := re.ReplaceAllStringFunc(str, func (match string) string {
    r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(match)
    return fmt.Sprintf("&#%d;", r)
  })

  fmt.Println(replaced) //=> "i like you hahahah &#128512; hello."
}
```

Here's the full regular expression to match all emoji characters in the [Emoji 14.0](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/emoji-test.txt) standard provided in the linked answer. Note that does not include emoji introduced recently, such as .

```golang
emojiRx := regexp.MustCompile(`[#*0-9]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|©\x{FE0F}?|[®\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}\x{21AA}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{231A}\x{231B}]|[\x{2328}\x{23CF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{23E9}-\x{23EC}]|[\x{23ED}-\x{23EF}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{23F0}|[\x{23F1}\x{23F2}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{23F3}|[\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}\x{25FC}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{25FD}\x{25FE}]|[\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2614}\x{2615}]|\x{2618}\x{FE0F}?|\x{261D}[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{2620}\x{2622}\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2648}-\x{2653}]|[\x{265F}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267E}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{267F}|\x{2692}\x{FE0F}?|\x{2693}|[\x{2694}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}\x{269C}\x{26A0}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{26A1}|\x{26A7}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{26AA}\x{26AB}]|[\x{26B0}\x{26B1}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{26BD}\x{26BE}\x{26C4}\x{26C5}]|\x{26C8}\x{FE0F}?|\x{26CE}|[\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{26D4}|\x{26E9}\x{FE0F}?|\x{26EA}|[\x{26F0}\x{26F1}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{26F2}\x{26F3}]|\x{26F4}\x{FE0F}?|\x{26F5}|[\x{26F7}\x{26F8}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{26F9}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{26FA}\x{26FD}]|\x{2702}\x{FE0F}?|\x{2705}|[\x{2708}\x{2709}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{270A}\x{270B}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{270C}\x{270D}][\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{270F}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2728}|[\x{2733}\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{274C}\x{274E}\x{2753}-\x{2755}\x{2757}]|\x{2763}\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F525}\x{1FA79}]|\x{FE0F}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F525}\x{1FA79}])?)?|[\x{2795}-\x{2797}]|\x{27A1}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{27B0}\x{27BF}]|[\x{2934}\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}]|[\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F004}\x{1F0CF}]|[\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}]|\x{1F1E6}[\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FD}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E7}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}-\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E8}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FA}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E9}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1EA}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1EB}[\x{1F1EE}-\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}]|\x{1F1EC}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}-\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1ED}[\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1EE}[\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1F9}]|\x{1F1EF}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}]|\x{1F1F0}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F1}[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1F2}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F3}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}-\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F2}|\x{1F1F5}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1EA}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1F6}\x{1F1E6}|\x{1F1F7}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}]|\x{1F1F8}[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FD}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F9}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EF}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1FA}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1FB}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1FC}[\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1F8}]|\x{1F1FD}\x{1F1F0}|\x{1F1FE}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F9}]|\x{1F1FF}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1FC}]|\x{1F201}|\x{1F202}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}-\x{1F236}]|\x{1F237}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F238}-\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}\x{1F251}\x{1F300}-\x{1F320}]|[\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F32C}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F32D}-\x{1F335}]|\x{1F336}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F337}-\x{1F37C}]|\x{1F37D}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F37E}-\x{1F384}]|\x{1F385}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F386}-\x{1F393}]|[\x{1F396}\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}\x{1F39F}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3A0}-\x{1F3C1}]|\x{1F3C2}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F3C5}\x{1F3C6}]|\x{1F3C7}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F3C8}\x{1F3C9}]|\x{1F3CA}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F3CB}\x{1F3CC}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F3CD}\x{1F3CE}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3CF}-\x{1F3D3}]|[\x{1F3D4}-\x{1F3DF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3E0}-\x{1F3F0}]|\x{1F3F3}(?:\x{200D}(?:\x{26A7}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F308})|\x{FE0F}(?:\x{200D}(?:\x{26A7}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F308}))?)?|\x{1F3F4}(?:\x{200D}\x{2620}\x{FE0F}?|\x{E0067}\x{E0062}(?:\x{E0065}\x{E006E}\x{E0067}|\x{E0073}\x{E0063}\x{E0074}|\x{E0077}\x{E006C}\x{E0073})\x{E007F})?|[\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3F8}-\x{1F407}]|\x{1F408}(?:\x{200D}\x{2B1B})?|[\x{1F409}-\x{1F414}]|\x{1F415}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F9BA})?|[\x{1F416}-\x{1F43A}]|\x{1F43B}(?:\x{200D}\x{2744}\x{FE0F}?)?|[\x{1F43C}-\x{1F43E}]|\x{1F43F}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F440}|\x{1F441}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}\x{FE0F}?|\x{FE0F}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F442}\x{1F443}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F444}\x{1F445}]|[\x{1F446}-\x{1F450}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F451}-\x{1F465}]|[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F468}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}]|\x{1F466}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})?|\x{1F467}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])?|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]\x{200D}(?:\x{1F466}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})?|\x{1F467}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])?)|[\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FB}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FC}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FD}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FE}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FF}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?)?|\x{1F469}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}]|\x{1F466}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})?|\x{1F467}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])?|\x{1F469}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F466}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})?|\x{1F467}(?:\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])?)|[\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FB}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FC}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FD}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FE}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FF}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?)?|\x{1F46A}|[\x{1F46B}-\x{1F46D}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F46E}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F46F}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?|[\x{1F470}\x{1F471}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F472}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F473}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F474}-\x{1F476}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F477}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F478}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F479}-\x{1F47B}]|\x{1F47C}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F47D}-\x{1F480}]|[\x{1F481}\x{1F482}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F483}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F484}|\x{1F485}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F486}\x{1F487}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F488}-\x{1F48E}]|\x{1F48F}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F490}|\x{1F491}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F492}-\x{1F4A9}]|\x{1F4AA}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F4AB}-\x{1F4FC}]|\x{1F4FD}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F4FF}-\x{1F53D}]|[\x{1F549}\x{1F54A}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F54B}-\x{1F54E}\x{1F550}-\x{1F567}]|[\x{1F56F}\x{1F570}\x{1F573}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F574}[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F575}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F576}-\x{1F579}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F57A}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F590}[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F595}\x{1F596}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F5A4}|[\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F5FB}-\x{1F62D}]|\x{1F62E}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F4A8})?|[\x{1F62F}-\x{1F634}]|\x{1F635}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F4AB})?|\x{1F636}(?:\x{200D}\x{1F32B}\x{FE0F}?)?|[\x{1F637}-\x{1F644}]|[\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F648}-\x{1F64A}]|\x{1F64B}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F64C}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F64F}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6A2}]|\x{1F6A3}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F6A4}-\x{1F6B3}]|[\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F6B7}-\x{1F6BF}]|\x{1F6C0}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F6C1}-\x{1F6C5}]|\x{1F6CB}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F6CC}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F6CD}-\x{1F6CF}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F6D0}-\x{1F6D2}\x{1F6D5}-\x{1F6D7}\x{1F6DD}-\x{1F6DF}]|[\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F6EB}\x{1F6EC}]|[\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F6F4}-\x{1F6FC}\x{1F7E0}-\x{1F7EB}\x{1F7F0}]|\x{1F90C}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F90D}\x{1F90E}]|\x{1F90F}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F910}-\x{1F917}]|[\x{1F918}-\x{1F91F}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F920}-\x{1F925}]|\x{1F926}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F927}-\x{1F92F}]|[\x{1F930}-\x{1F934}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F935}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F936}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F93A}|\x{1F93C}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?|[\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F93F}-\x{1F945}\x{1F947}-\x{1F976}]|\x{1F977}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F978}-\x{1F9B4}]|[\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F9B7}|[\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F9BA}|\x{1F9BB}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F9BC}-\x{1F9CC}]|[\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F9D0}|\x{1F9D1}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FB}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}|)\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FC}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}|)\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FD}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}|)\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FE}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}|)\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|\x{1F3FF}(?:\x{200D}(?:[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}?|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}|)\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}]|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?)?|[\x{1F9D2}\x{1F9D3}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F9D4}(?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|\x{1F9D5}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?)?|[\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}](?:\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]\x{FE0F}?)?|[\x{1F9E0}-\x{1F9FF}\x{1FA70}-\x{1FA74}\x{1FA78}-\x{1FA7C}\x{1FA80}-\x{1FA86}\x{1FA90}-\x{1FAAC}\x{1FAB0}-\x{1FABA}\x{1FAC0}-\x{1FAC2}]|[\x{1FAC3}-\x{1FAC5}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|[\x{1FAD0}-\x{1FAD9}\x{1FAE0}-\x{1FAE7}]|\x{1FAF0}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1FAF1}(?:\x{1F3FB}(?:\x{200D}\x{1FAF2}[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}])?|\x{1F3FC}(?:\x{200D}\x{1FAF2}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}])?|\x{1F3FD}(?:\x{200D}\x{1FAF2}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}])?|\x{1F3FE}(?:\x{200D}\x{1FAF2}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}])?|\x{1F3FF}(?:\x{200D}\x{1FAF2}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}])?)?|[\x{1FAF2}-\x{1FAF6}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?`)
```