# Regex to allow "safe" characters and all emojis

Tags: regex, go

I am writing a simple tool to allow people to label jobs on a server. The allowed characters are below. In addition to this, I want to allow emojis (any emojis).

I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575798/how-to-replace-emoji-characters-in-string-using-regex-in-golang) stackoverflow question for the latter. But when I try to combine them, the code does not work.

Here's my function:

```golang
func SafeCharsRegex() *regexp.Regexp {
    regexString := "A-Za-z0-9._~!:@,;+-"
    emojiString := `[©®‼⁉™ℹ↔-↙↩↪⌨⏏⏭-⏯⏱⏲⏸-⏺Ⓜ▪▫▶◀◻◼☀-☄☎☑☘☠☢☣☦☪☮☯☸-☺♀♂♟♠♣♥♦♨♻♾⚒⚔-⚗⚙⚛⚜⚠⚧⚰⚱⛈⛏⛑⛓⛩⛰⛱⛴⛷⛸✂✈✉✏✒✔✖✝✡✳✴❄❇❣➡⤴⤵⬅-⬇〰〽㊗㊙----------]️?|[☝✌✍][️-]?|[⛹](?:‍[♀♂]️?|[️-](?:‍[♀♂]️?)?)?|[✊✋-------][-]?|❤(?:‍[]|️(?:‍[])?)?|[--]|[---]|[---]|[]|[-]|[-]|[---]|[]|[---]|[]|[-]|[--]|[--]|[-]||[---]||[]|[----]|[--]|[]|[]|[]||[]|[]|[-----](?:‍[♀♂]️?|[-](?:‍[♀♂]️?)?)?|(?:‍(?:⚧️?|)|️(?:‍(?:⚧️?|))?)?|(?:‍☠️?|(?:||))?|(?:‍⬛)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍❄️?)?|(?:‍️?|️(?:‍️?)?)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|[]‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:[]|‍[])|(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?|‍(?:(?:‍)?|(?:‍[])?)|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[][-]|‍[][-]|[-]))?)?|[](?:‍[♀♂]️?)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍)?|(?:‍️?)?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|‍|[-])|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?|(?:‍(?:[⚕⚖✈]️?|❤️?‍(?:‍)?[-]|‍[-]|[-]))?)?|[⌚⌛⏩-⏬⏰⏳◽◾☔☕♈-♓♿⚓⚡⚪⚫⚽⚾⛄⛅⛎⛔⛪⛲⛳⛵⛺⛽✅✨❌❎❓-❕❗➕-➗➰➿⬛⬜⭐⭕-----------------------------------------------------]|(?:(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[])?|(?:‍[-])?|(?:‍[-])?)?`

    r := regexp.MustCompile(fmt.Sprintf("[^%s|%s]", regexString, emojiString))
    return r
}
```

and here's how I'm using it.

```
    s := ""
    r := SafeCharsRegex()
    safeString := r.ReplaceAllString(s, "")
```

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR: safeString == ""

ACTUAL BEHAVIOR: safeString == ""

I've tried removing the concetatenation, doing just the emoji string, etc, and nothing works. However, when I make the emojiString JUST those four emojis, it does work. So there's something with the VERY complex emoji string that's broken.

HOWEVER, when I go here - https://regex101.com/r/iCzyv2/1 - it works fine.

Comment: Remove outer square brackets from `emojiString`. Also, remove `|` from the new pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A better way may be thinking in terms of unicode. Unicode has something called [character category (or class)](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html#categories), which are tagged with a specific "name". And some regex specifications define tokens that matches specific classes. From what I see you want to match letters (which has the name `L`, note that this includes letters like `é`), numbers (with the name `N`), punctuation (named `P`), and symbols (named `S`).

By reading the [documentation of the `regex` package](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#pkg-overview), we can learn that it implements the [`RE2` syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). And to specify a token that matches an unicode character class, like numbers, we can use `\p{N}`. So, we can define a regex like:

```
[\p{L}\p{P}\p{S}\p{N}]+
```

Which will fully match the string `thisis_atest998`

Considering that since you have such a permissive filter (what is not allowed here? whitespaces?), it may be better to find for non-allowed symbols instead.

Comment: Thanks! I dunno - my mental space is to go to only allowed characters in such a large attack surface. I'll mess around with this syntax though, it may be an elegant solution.

My goal was to allow a very small set of characters that are allowed in a URL without translation (the regex string) and every emoji.